# Is there a way to create a zooming image assigned to exit Form windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

How do I zoom out a picture on cursor with `C#` on Visual Studio?
so I'm making a `windows form` program with C# via Visual Studio and I placed an image assigned to close the application (form) but I want this image to zoom when the mouse cursor is overit.
I'm really new to developing and I have no clue

Comment: Hi Captain Syria,
  Could you show what you've tried so far please?

Comment: It would much more easy to help you if you provide the relevant part of your code in your question.

Comment: I have tried to code nothing for this matter, as i told you, i'm new in this coding world...
But i managed to make what i mentioned above by adding a framework to VisualStudio called "Bunifu UI" therefore i can add a component from toolbox called "Bunifu_Image_Button" and from properties i can activate zoom misc so the image zooms a little bit when the cursor is on it...

 I would still be more than happy if you teach me to code such a thing by my own.

Thank you @SebastianInones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your problem, you would like to make a picture to close the app, which can zoom

the picture.

In winform, I recommend that you use picturebox.

You can look at the following code example.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\1.JPG");
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              pictureBox1.Size = new Size(120, 94);

        }
        private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                pictureBox1.Size = new Size(60,47);
        }
    }
```

Tested result:

[image]

Comment: Yeah. that is exactly what i wanted. thank you so much!